# retrieve Json Object's property returned from $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am unable to parse a property from JSON object. Since this is just one JSON object, I am not sure if I need to do `$.each` or I can directly grab properties as `data.d.property`. Can someone explain how I do about grabbing properties value from this object?

This is what I have:

```
jQ(document).ready(function() {  
  var listDataURL = "";
  var root =  getParameterByName('RootFolder');
  var rootFolderID = getParameterByName("ID");
  var docSetTitle = root.substr(root.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);      
  listDataURL = "http://SomeSite/sites/TestWF/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ResumeBank(" + rootFolderID +")";
      //use the getJSON mehtod of Jquery
      jQ.getJSON(listDataURL, function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
        //iterate through all the items 
         jQ.each(data.d.results, function(i, result) {          
          //get child items count for the current set           
          ChildItemCount = result.ItemChildCount;
          NumOfItemsApproved = result.ApprovalCounter;

          });
          if (ChildItemCount !== NumOfItemsApproved){
            alert("Ah ah! The ApprovalCounter got skewed and needs to be fixed.");
          }
          if (ChildItemCount === NumOfItemsApproved){
            alert("ApprovalCounter looks good!");
          }
      });
});
```

And the JSON response is the below, I am trying to grab the value of `ApprovalCounter`:

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "__metadata":{  
         "uri":"http://collaboration/sites/TestWF/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ResumeBank(84)",
         "etag":"W/\"12\"",
         "type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.ResumeBankItem",
         "edit_media":"http://collaboration/sites/TestWF/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ResumeBank(84)/$value",
         "media_src":"http://collaboration/sites/TestWF",
         "content_type":"text/xml"
      },
      "Id":84,
      "ContentTypeID":"0x0120D52000E387E9726C57FE40807A71CC05BEF45A005D5A666FE9576E42B629AF7CDB33F1B0",
      "ContentType":"JobApplication",
      "Created":"\/Date(1413213951000)\/",
      "CreatedBy":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"http://collaboration/sites/TestWF/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ResumeBank(84)/CreatedBy"
         }
      },
      "CreatedById":1,
      "Modified":"\/Date(1413561633000)\/",
      "ModifiedBy":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"http://collaboration/sites/TestWF/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ResumeBank(84)/ModifiedBy"
         }
      },
      "ModifiedById":1,
      "CopySource":null,
      "ApprovalStatus":"2",
      "ApproverComments":null,
      "Path":"/sites/TestWF/ResumeBank",
      "CheckedOutTo":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"http://collaboration/sites/TestWF/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ResumeBank(84)/CheckedOutTo"
         }
      },
      "CheckedOutToId":null,
      "Name":"Tabitha Johnson",
      "VirusStatus":"",
      "IsCurrentVersion":true,
      "Owshiddenversion":12,
      "Version":"1.0",
      "Title":"Tabitha Johnson",
      "Description":null,
      "RoleAppliedFor":"HR Assistant",
      "HiringDepartment":{  
         "__deferred":{  
            "uri":"http://collaboration/sites/TestWF/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ResumeBank(84)/HiringDepartment"
         }
      },
      "HiringDepartmentValue":"HR",
      "FirstRoundApproval":null,
      "StartDate":"\/Date(1413158400000)\/",
      "ApprovalCounter":0,
      "Education":null,
      "Experience":null,
      "ApproveEachDoc":null,
      "ApproveDocSet1st":"2",
      "ApproveDocSet2nd":"2"
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the JSON itself (as in `JSON.parse`)? I think jQuery will automatically parse the JSON before handing you `data`.

Comment: there is no `d.results` you just want `data.d.ApprovalCounter` without using `each`

Comment: Sorry I meant retrieve properties of the JSON Object.

Comment: @SariksaThapa It's only json when it's a string. `data` is a javascript object that was created by parsing a json string.

Comment: What are you trying to access? There's no array to iterate, though you could iterate each of the properties... if you want an individual property, it would look like `data.d.HiringDepartment` or `data.d.ContentType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `$.each()` function.

```
jQ.each(data.d.results, function(i, result) { ... }
```

$.each() is looking for an array to iterate over, and then a callback as parameters.

Your array is all the json objects nested in your "d" object. That's good.

Your callback is specifying a "key-value" pair `function(i, result)` where when the loop reaches the `{ "ApprovalCounter" : "0" }` object, i = "Approval Counter" and result = "0." ... so `results.Anything` is going to throw an error.

**Long Story Short:**

Change it to:

```
JQ.each(data.d.results, function(results)) {
    //...
    var count = results.ApprovalCounter;
    //...
}
```

and it should work...

**Alternatively:**

You don't need to use the $.each() loop at all to just access the value from "ApprovalCounter."

```
data.d.ApprovalCounter
```

... should return "0."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

It should just be data.d.ApprovalCounter